@error: Equation Definition : Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<) : true
I am buliding a Structural Optimization project by selecting optimal cross sections(continous var) and material (integer vars) for my finite element model. The following is my run_simulation :
from gekko import GEKKO
optimizer  = GEKKO(remote = False) # Create a GEKKO object
num_vars = len(initial_opt_vars) // 2 

# Continous vars 
x_continuous = [optimizer.Var(value=0.005, lb=0) for _ in range(num_vars)]
        
# Integer Vars
x_integer = [optimizer.sos1([0, 1, 2]) for _ in range(num_vars)]  # SOS1 for selecting among discrete options
        
optimizer.Minimize(self.objective_function(x_continuous, x_integer))
        
stress_expr = self.stress_constraint(x_continuous, x_integer)
        
optimizer.Equation([expr >= 0 for expr in stress_expr])

optimizer.options.SOLVER = 1
optimizer.solve(disp = True)

Inside the constraints function and the objective function I am using the current values of the optimization to solve the finite element model. The Output of the constraints is an numpy array with 542 elements. I don't know why the inequality expression is wrong and I don't know how to proceed from there.
The error :
error: Equation Definition
 Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
 true
 STOPPING...

Can please someone assist me on that one ?
Structural Optimization for a Finite Element Analysis model .
My gk_model0.apm has the following structure :
Model
Variables
    v1 = 0.005, >= 0
    v2 = 0.005, >= 0

-
    v270 = 0.005, >= 0
    v271 = 0.005, >= 0
    int_v272 = 0.01, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v273 = 0.01, <= 1, >= 0
-
    int_v1352 = 0.01, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v1353 = 0.01, <= 1, >= 0
    int_v1354 = 0.01, <= 1, >= 0
    v1355 = 0
End Variables
Intermediates
    i0=(((0+((0)*(int_v272)))+((1)*(int_v273)))+((2)*(int_v274)))
    i1=(((0+((0)*(int_v276)))+((1)*(int_v277)))+((2)*(int_v278)))
-
    i269=(((0+((0)*(int_v1348)))+((1)*(int_v1349)))+((2)*(int_v1350)))
    i270=(((0+((0)*(int_v1352)))+((1)*(int_v1353)))+((2)*(int_v1354)))
End Intermediates
Equations
    (((0+int_v272)+int_v273)+int_v274)=1
    v275=i0
    (((0+int_v276)+int_v277)+int_v278)=1
-
    v1351=i269
    (((0+int_v1352)+int_v1353)+int_v1354)=1
    v1355=i270
    True
    True
-
    True
    minimize 776.8284358905587
End Equations

End Model


Here is a related project for shielding layer optimization for nuclear microreactors that uses ML models as surrogates for the black-box model: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/shielding

The functions self.objective_function(x_continuous, x_integer) and self.stress_constraint(x_continuous, x_integer) are calls to external code. The Gekko variables are passed into the functions, but Gekko can't extract information from that functions that it needs for gradient-based solutions. One strategy for dealing with black-box models is to create a surrogate function depending on the number of function inputs.

With a 1d function, use a cubic spline
For a 2d function, use a bspline
For a higher dimensional function, use machine learning in gekko to regress and import a surrogate model such as a neural network, gaussian process regression, support vector regressor, or others.

Besides gradient-based optimization, another approach is to use gradient-free methods such as simulated annealing, a genetic algorithm (see Chap 6), or others that are described in the Engineering Optimization course.
